# Bootstrap Typeahead Bloodhound tokenizer doesn't work with mulitple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var people = new Bloodhound({
              datumTokenizer: function(d) { return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.tokens); },
              queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
              local: [
                { 
                    fullName: '',
                    "],
                },
                { 
                    fullName: 'Marijus Merkevicius', 
                    tokens: ["Marijus Merkevicius", "marijusm"],
                },
              ]
            }); 

        // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine
        people.initialize();

        // instantiate the typeahead UI
        $('#${id }').typeahead(null, {
          displayKey: 'fullName',
          source: people.ttAdapter(),
        });

    }); 
</script>
```

When I use return `Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.fullName);` autocomplete works perfectly however when I return d.tokens it doesn't at all. What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tokens is an array and it is expecting a string. You could try `d.tokens.join(' ')`, though not sure if you need a jQuery selector (`$`) around d.